# GetScheduledTaskInfo NextRunTime is wrong

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to use Powershell to get the NextRunTime for some scheduled tasks.  I'm retrieving the values but they don't match up to what I'm seeing in the Task Scheduler Management Console.

For example, in the Task Scheduler console my "TestTask" has a Next Run Time value of "1/9/2018 12:52:**30** PM".  But when I do the following call in Powershell it shows "12:52:**52** PM" for the NextRunTime.

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TestTask" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
```

From what I've seen the seconds value is always the same value as the minutes when returned from the PowerShell `Get-ScheduledTaskInfo` cmdlet.  I'm wondering if there's a time formatting error (hh:mm:mm instead of hh:mm:ss) in that cmdlet but I have no idea how to look for that.
The task is running at the exact time shown in the console so that makes me think that it's an issue with the powershell call.

Has anyone seen this issue before and know how to get the correct NextRunTime value in PowerShell?  I'm also seeing the same issue with the LastRunTime value.

I've tried this on Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 and get the same results on both operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that I see the same issue on Server 2012R2 as well. You can get the correct information by using the task scheduler COM object, getting the root folder (or whatever folder your task is stored in, but most likely its in the root folder), and then getting the task info from that. Here's how you'd do it:

```
$Scheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$Scheduler.Connect()
$RootFolder = $Scheduler.GetFolder("\")
$Task = $RootFolder.GetTask("TestTask")
$Task.NextRunTime
```

Probably also worth noting that you can use the `Connect()` method to connect to the task scheduler on other computers (if you have rights to access their task scheduler), and get information about their tasks, stop or start their tasks, make new tasks... lots of good stuff here if you don't mind not using the `*-ScheduledTask*` cmdlets.

Comment: I was going to say, I see the same thing on Server 2016, 2012 R2, and Windows 10.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the confirmation and the work-around.
I submitted a bug report on the Feedback Hub inside Windows 10, apparently the Windows Server team doesn't own that cmdlet so that's where they said to submit the bug.  It can be seen here:  https://insider.windows.com/en-us/fb/?contextid=268&feedbackid=959bb25c-1afb-425f-8f91-ae3919da0d63&form=1