# Schtask script to email status of a job

Tags: powershell

Need some help

I'm running a command in PS to query a task

schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn '\Receive Orders'

Get a result

Folder: \

HostName:      My-Server-VM

TaskName:      \Receive Orders

Next Run Time: 2/25/2020 2:40:00 PM

Status:        Ready

Logon Mode:    Interactive/Background

What I would like to get from the query is this

Look at the status if the status is "Ready" do nothing if the Status is "Running" send me an email.

I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: what have you tried already thats not working? schtasks is an executable... and nothing to do with powershell. can you share your code you've tried so far ?

Comment: I tried creating a Task to look at the job when its running, if it runs to long wanted to email me letting me know that the job was running. This did not work as intendet. Found that I can run this in PowerShell and it gave me the result I wanted now I just need put a statement to let me know yes its running and send me an email. I'm not really a script guy as I a fairly new to this and have been put in a situation where I have to come up with a way to get that info for my boss.

Comment: Can you show us the code in powershell you have written so far. SO is not a code writing service but can provide you insights on the code you have written but not working

Comment: Ok I will I'm fighting through this right now all I have is this schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn '\Receive Orders'. It is giving me the correct output, I am trying to figure out how it look at the status and send me an email when it says Running. I understand that this is not a code writing service, just wanted some pointers on how to go about this.

Comment: Rather than trying to parse the text results of schtasks.exe perhaps you could use the scheduler service to view the tasks directly as objects in PowerShell. You can see a brief example of looking up a scheduled task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176028/3245749).

Comment: I'm getting the result I want with schtask or if I use Get-Scheduled Task, I just don't know how what to put next so I can get an email of the result for 'Receive Task' job. I just need an email stating yes this job is running now, that's it. I tried using scheduled job with event code but that is not working like I want it to.

Comment: $scheduledtask=Get-ScheduledTask -name 'Receive Orders'
 Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Running' -and $_.TaskName -eq "$scheduledtask"}. This should return a value of Running if that is returned than it should email me. I'm sorry just lost.